# RegEx to find pattern " JUNKCHARS" in Javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider below String,

```
var originalStr = "This is first string JUNKCHARS";
```

I need a regex to find a pattern " JUNKCHAR", i.e. characters JUNKCHAR with (any number of) whitespace before it and end of string after it.

```
e.g, 

// case 1
originalStr = "This is first string JUNKCHARS";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first string

// case 2
originalStr = "This is first string            JUNKCHARS";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first string

// case 3
originalStr = "This is first string JUNKCHARS    ";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first string JUNKCHARS    

// case 4
originalStr = "This is first string JUNKCHARS test";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first string JUNKCHARS test    

// case 5
originalStr = "This is first stringJUNKCHAR";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first stringJUNKCHAR

// case 6
originalStr = "This is first string JUNKCHARtest";

replacedStr = originalStr.replace(<pattern>, "");

console.log(replacedStr); // should output - This is first string JUNKCHARtest
```

I have tried several regex but none seems to meet my requirement. Could anyone please help me in finding the right regex. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: So in case 3 for instance, we do NOT remove JUNKCHAR? Not understanding the rule.

Comment: yes, we do not remove JUNKCHAR because there is a space after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through that pattern by part

1. You want to match a number of whitespaces, but at least one, so that gives us `\s+`
2. You want to match the string `JUNKCHARS`
3. You want the end of the string, which is `$` in regex syntax

Together you'll get `var pattern = /\s+JUNKCHARS$/`

You can fiddle around with it http://regex101.com/r/sU4eI3/1

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
var text = 'This is first string JUNKCHARS    ';
text = text.replace(/\s{2,}JUNKCHARS/g,'').trim();
console.log(text);
```

Here is a demo: http://jqversion.com/#!/NYBiNrT

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

(?:^|\s)(JUNKCHARS)(?=\s|$)|\sJUNKCHARS\s